# Xcode playground and initialize NSImage

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I'm coding with Xcode playground but I got error at the first line of my code:

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground

let image = NSImage(size: NSSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

With initialising image a got two errors:

> ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination must have at
>   least one image CGImageDestinationFinalize failed for output type
>   'public.tiff'

Do anybody know what is going on?

Comment: Why don't you use `UIImage` ?

Comment: According first line (import Cocoa) it's MacOS playground, there in no UIImage in Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code in ObjC, it worked, but in Swift it doesn't work (also NSImage() doesn't work)?
According to Apple doc. NSImage init(size aSize: NSSize):

> This method does not add any image representations to the image
>   object. It is permissible to initialize the image object by passing a
>   size of (0.0, 0.0); however, you must set the size to a non-zero value
>   before using it or an exception will be raised.

Probably Swift requires NSImage to be initialized with an image. This works in playground:

```
let image = NSImage(named: NSImageNameQuickLookTemplate)
if let image = image {
   image.size = NSSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
println(image?.size)
```

Comment: this works, but I want to initialize empty NSImage, like in ObjC
I submit it to Apple Bug reporter